# Modify permissions of a file generated using CPIO extract

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions, cpio

I have a **CPIO** package to be extracted. It has some set of files say x1,x2,....xN. While extracting, these files are being generated with 777 permission.

But I want it to be generated with 755 permission. Is there a way where I can use pipe to modify permissions of the files generated out of the CPIO.

Comment: You would need a pipe that modifies the permissions inside the CPIO archive. I don't think that such a program exists. You could use `umask 022` before running `cpio -o ...`.

Comment: Thanks @Bodo. I tried many options but dint work out.Then I wrote a custom script to handle this scenario.

Comment: You should add the "*many options*" to your question and show how exactly it "*didn't work out*". If you found a solution, you can write answer for your question yourself.